# How to and multiple test run using add_result per Testrail

Tags: ruby, cucumber, testrail

I am using ruby Cucumber and I am updating the test result on Testrail.
I can update one result without issue.
My question is , per the code below, how can I update multiple test run using the add_result method?

```
 require 'testrail-ruby'
  client = TestRail::APIClient.new('https:XXXXXt/')
  client.user = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  client.password = 'XXXXXXXXX'
  r = client.send_post(
      'add_result/483750',
      { :status_id => 1, :comment => 'This test worked fine!' }
  )
  #puts r
end
```

Comment: Untested (and I'm assuming that 483750 is the test run identifier), but you could create an array of test run identifiers and then iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of luck with the `testrail_client` gem. It is very similar: https://rubygems.org/gems/testrail_client/versions/0.0.1

```
data =[{
    "test_id" => 1234
    "status_id" => status_value,
    "comment" => "blarg"
}]


url = "https://canvas.testrail.com"
trclient = TestRail::APIClient.new(url)
trclient.user = ENV["TESTRAIL_USER"]
trclient.password = ENV["TESTRAIL_PASSWORD"]

uri = "add_results/#{run_id}"
trclient.send_post_retry(uri, "results" => data)
```

If you are using rspec, there is a gem that auto posts results to testrail: `testrailtagging`. The `TESTRAIL_BATCH_SIZE` env variable helps from being throttled by tetrail.